# What is the difference between these two JavaScript/JQuery techniques?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

What is the difference between these two approaches? I am trying to understand Jquery and JavaScript better. Thanks in advance SO!

```
        /**
        * What is the difference between these two techniques?
        */

        /* Using JQuery Extend */

        var names = {name1 : 'Nicholas', name2: 'Bobby'}
        var ages = {age1 : '27', age2: '32'}
        var profile = $.extend(names, ages);
        console.log(profile.name1, profile.age1)

        /* By filling a blank object with the combined dataset */

        var names = { name1 : 'Nicholas', name2 : 'Bobby'}
        var ages = { age1 : '27', age2 : '32'}
        var profile = {};
        profile.names = names;
        profile.ages = ages;
        console.log(profile.names.name1, profile.ages.age1)
```

Comment: Both are totally different!!!

Comment: Have a look at the results of each.  You should easily see how they differ.

Comment: Have you read the [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) documentation? *"Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object."* The other one is just assigning object to an object properties.

Comment: [**Look at your console here**](http://jsfiddle.net/e0341pe7/) and see the difference.

Comment: The results are the same in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/10399ddcf8a239acc27bdec9231b996b178224d3/src/core.js#L124) of `jQuery.fn.extend()` in GitHub:
It parses through the given object and makes a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy) of the whole object. So, when the object has subobjects, they are deep copied too.
The usage is explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) as follows:

> Description: Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

Whereas

```
    var names = { name1 : 'Nicholas', name2 : 'Bobby'}
    var ages = { age1 : '27', age2 : '32'}
    var profile = {};
    profile.names = names;
    profile.ages = ages;
```

does not copy at all. It puts those objects together in one `super`- or `wrapping`-object.

The very difference is, that after `extending`, both objects are independend and with the second way not. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tt5p1q6f/). The new object contains only *references* to the old objects instead of a `deep copy`.

Comment: Thanks for the easy to understand answer!

Answer (score 2):

`$.extend` merges two objects. The result of the first code is a single object containing all the properties of the two objects:

```
{name1 : 'Nicholas', age1: '27', name2: 'Bobby', age2: '32'}
```

It also modifies its first argument as a side effect. So this result will be in both `profile` and `names`. To prevent the first argument from being modified, use `$.extend({}, names, ages)`.

To access one of the values from this, you would use `profile.name1` or `profile.age2`.

Your second code creates a new object that contains the first two objects as different properties within it:

```
{ names: {name1 : 'Nicholas', name2: 'Bobby'},
  ages: { age1 : '27', age2 : '32'}
}
```

To access one of the values from this, you would use `profile.names.name1` or `profile.ages.age2`.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery extend method combines the names and ages objects. Your second example creates a new object with the preceding objects as keys.